# How split text by one character but not inside valid quoted strings

Tags: javascript

I need to split text by pipe character but it should not split if it's in the middle of single or double quoted strings, taking into account that the quotes can be escaped and it should not split if the pipe is escaped with od number of slashes, test cases:

input: "foo bar | baz"
otuput: ["foo bar", "baz"]

input: 'foo "bar" | baz'
output: ['foo "bar"', "baz"]

input: "foo 'bar\' | baz'"
output: ["foo 'bar\' | baz'"]

input: "foo 'bar\\' | baz"
output: ["foo 'bar\\'", "baz"]

input: "foo 'bar\\' \| baz"
output ["foo 'bar\\' \| baz"]

In php I have this regex:

```
const separators = "/(?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\S\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\S\s][^'\\\\]*)*')(*SKIP)(*F)|(\s+(?:&&|\|{1,2}|;)\s+)/";
```

but javascript don't have `(*SKIP)` so it probably not possible with regex and creating parser using parser generator is overkill it should be easy task by creating small function.

Answer (score 0):

I've created small function that parse the string:

```
     function split(string) {
         var output = [];
         var quote = false;
         var start = 0;
         function is_escaped() {
             return string.substring(start, i).match(/(\\\\)*\\$/);
         }
         for (var i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
             if (string[i] === '"' || string[i] === "'") {
                 if (!is_escaped()) {
                     quote = !quote;
                 }
             } else if (string[i] === '|' && !quote) {
                 if (!is_escaped()) {
                     output.push(string.substring(start, i));
                     start = i + 1;
                 }
             }
             if (i == string.length - 1) {
                 output.push(string.substring(start));
             }
         }
         return output.map(function(string) {
             return string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
         });
     }
```